# Adding element to Active NavLink React

Tags: reactjs, menubar

I'm trying to add a dot below the navigation link. As a result, when the Chat is active it should be a dot below the word "chat" and when the profile is active below the "profile" word should be a dot and under "chat" - nothing.
In my version, I don't see dots.
In the final version, a menu link and a dot should be flex-direction: column;
align-items: center; ( I will do it with flex)

```
const FooterChatProfile = () => (
<nav className="footer-chat-profile">
  <NavLink
  exact
  activeClassName="footer-link-active"
  className="footer-link"
  to="/Overview"
  >Chat
    <div 
    activeClassName="footer-dot-active"
    className="footer-dot"
      to="/Overview"> </div>
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink
  activeClassName="footer-link-active"
  className="footer-link"
  to="/profile"
  >
    Profile
    <div 
    activeClassName="footer-dot-active"
    className="footer-dot"
      to="/profile"> </div>
    
  </NavLink>
</nav>
)

export default FooterChatProfile;
```

`And CSS`

```
.footer-link {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #181818;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.footer-link-active {
  /* border-bottom: 3px solid #3e99c0; */
  transition: border-bottom .5s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer-dot-active {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3e99c0;
  
}
.footer-dot {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `activeClassName` in the `div` inside the `NavLink` is ignored (`activeClassName` is only for `NavLink`). You have to target it via:

```
.footer-link-active > .footer-dot {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3e99c0;
}
```

Comment: I faced with one more issue, React does not recognize the `activeClassName` prop on a DOM element. So activeClassName is ok with NavLink but causes warning when it's in div

Comment: And I fixed it. I left Uppercase in NavLink and change to lowercase in div